# Не работают CSS-подсказки в PhpStorm

Tags: css, phpstorm

Если в файле подключен CSS например:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/css/uikit2.css">
```

то все ок, работают подсказки по классам, т.е. начинаешь вводить имя класса — предлагает из имеющихся...
Но если в файле не прописывать ссылку на CSS, то подсказки не выводятся.
(например, у меня есть файл шаблона где все стили прописываются, и файл с контентом где их прописывать не нужно, т.к. подключаются через файл шаблона).

Как заставить PhpStorm связать файл с нужным CSS и чтобы выводились подсказки?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в пустой строке, нажать сочетание клавиш "Alt + Enter".
Мне это помогло.

Либо же, `File > invalidate caches`. Не ставь галочки, а сразу нажми "Invalidate and Restart".

Либо же, зайди в `Settings > Editor > language injections`. И убери галочки со всего что НЕ `build-in`. Должно помочь.